# In Odoo / OpenERP 8, How to visible button Attachment for a specific group on a specific model form?

Tags: python, odoo

In Odoo / OpenERP 8, How do I visible button Attachment for a specific group on a specific model form? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can add **groups** attribute to that button in .xml file. like

Eg:
groups="group_eg"